# Am I out of line in giving a generic answer to this question?

Tags: discussion

Recently I answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/280942/why-is-firefox-ui-so-unresponsive?noredirect=1#comment353509_280942. My answer was then moved to a comment, which I find perfectly valid; I tend to lean towards answers maybe more than I should.

However, the original asker was angry that I gave a generic answer. I feel like it was reasonable - many, many people don't go through basic troubleshooting, and often find that their problem gets fixed when they do. So I wanted to get input from the community: was my suggestion too unhelpful or otherwise "bad" in any way? Or was the OP out of line in their answer?

Comment: One suggestion I would make is that you kick it up to moderators if the OP turns nasty, rather than respond.

Comment: Your answer wasn't very detailed, you say "Try standard Firefox troubleshooting, including safe mode" but don't provide any links to anywhere to show people how to do that.

Comment: now that question was deleted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Negative.

I find nothing offensive about that comment of yours.

P.S : Avoid 'answering' when you do not have an 'answer'. Please post a comment instead. You have the required reputation, so it shouldn't be an issue. Stack Exchange holds 'answers' with high regard, and as such, does not approve of them being used to just ask for clarifications or say thanks or anything else that does not directly answer the question.

P.P.S : Meta is an exception.

Comment: I can echo all of this. It was the correct suggestion to make. 90% of Firefox issues are caused by people installing *all* the extensions.